# IP design: master and slave

Tags: integrated-circuit, verilog

I am writing some RTL for IPs for personal learning. Right now, they don't implement any bus interfaces for communicating between each other. I was looking around and thought about implementing the Wishbone bus protocol as it is doesn't look to complicated.

I have a question regarding what exactly master/slaves means in the context of bus interface. Is it fair to say master makes request for data and slave responds to the request? Can slave make a request?

Also if I have 1 master and say 5 slaves, the master IP can communicate with ALL of the slave IP, but the slaves can only communicate with the master and not between each other (unless they go through the master?)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think that all your comments are correct.
A master requests data (or sends data) to the slaves.

A slave cannot originate a bus transaction. It must wait until the master communicates to it. In a bus with many slaves, the master can communicate with all of them but the slaves cannot communicate between them.

For many cases, this is just OK since the slaves don't even know of the existence of other slaves. When slaves have to communicate between them, usually a mailbox system is implemented where a slave that wants to communicate to other slave indicates this to the master. But it cannot originate transactions on the bus.

Answer (score 0):

A 'master' makes requests and a 'slave' responds to requests.  Similarly, a slave cannot make requests and the master cannot respond to requests.  The master device may drive (possibly shared) control (clock, chip select, read enable, write enable, address latch enable, etc.) and address lines.  Usually both the master and the slave can drive data (master for writes, slave for reads).  For some interfaces, it is possible for a device to implement both the 'master' and the 'slave' role - in this case, slave devices can make requests by taking on the bus master role.  And for some interfaces, it is possible to have multiple masters on the bus with some sort of arbitration.  Buses like PCI and PCI express support this functionality to enable direct memory access.